# Validate format parameter via config in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, content-type

Here is my situation:

I have my mvc-config.xml file for my web service set up to have JSON as the default media type. I also have favorParameter for the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver as true. Additionally, I have useNotAcceptableStatusCode as true so that not accepted formats will return a 406.

My question is: Is there a way, in the config, to trigger the 406 status code when someone passes in an unacceptable format parameter (format=foo)? Or must that be done with code?

Here is the config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.work.stuff.web.view.json.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="objectMapper">
                        <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <property name="marshaller">
                        <ref bean="Jaxb2Marshaller" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
        <property name="useNotAcceptableStatusCode" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper">
                        <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="Jaxb2Marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="Jaxb2Marshaller" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
    <bean id="JacksonSerializationConfig" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig"
        factory-bean="JacksonObjectMapper" factory-method="getSerializationConfig" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="JacksonSerializationConfig" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setSerializationInclusion" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion">NON_NULL</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="Jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Concepts</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Concept</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Terms</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Term</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Namespaces</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Namespace</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Subsets</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Subset</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Associations</value>
                <value>com.work.stuff.Association</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` doesn't seem to support such behaviour. For now, I think your best bet is to subclass it and override the `getMediaTypeFromParameter()` method to throw an exception if the media type is not supported.

You can throw any `RuntimeException` from that method, and if you annotate the exception class with `@ResponseStatus`, you can control the HTTP response code, e.g.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
public class FormatNotSupportedException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

In the longer term, I strongly encourage you to file an issue with http://jira.springsource.org, asking for such functionality to be added to `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. They should be able to add this as an optional behavioural parameter. It's requests like these that mean Spring keeps getting better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will file an issue (and accept and up vote when time limits come off).