# configuring the jacksonObjectMapper not working in spring mvc 3

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

What I am aiming to do is to configure spring mvc 3 to not return “null” object in json response.
I've asked the question [how to configure spring mvc 3 to not return "null" object in json response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049523/how-to-configure-spring-mvc-3-to-not-return-null-object-in-json-response) . And the suggestion I got is to configure the ObjectMapper, setting the serialization inclusion to JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL. So Based on [Spring configure @ResponseBody JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823358/spring-configure-responsebody-json-format), I did the following changes in spring config file. But I got the error "Rejected bean name 'jacksonObjectMapper': no URL paths identified  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:86-AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java" during app startup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
    <!--<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>-->

    <!-- Configures Handler Interceptors -->    
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <!-- Changes the locale when a 'locale' request parameter is sent; e.g. /?locale=de -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

   <!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
    <bean id="jacksonSerializationConfig" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig"
    factory-bean="jacksonObjectMapper" factory-method="getSerializationConfig" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonSerializationConfig" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setSerializationInclusion" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion">NON_DEFAULT</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


  <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have no idea why it's been rejected. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` cannot be used together. (ref: [spring forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81238-Conflict-between-lt-mvc-annotation-driven-gt-and-DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping)). Possible solution

1. do not use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. Declaring bean: `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`
   and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and other settings like validation, formatting.
2. use spring 3.1, which has `<mvc:message-converters>` (ref: [Spring jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7504))

Comment: I found [this blog post](http://software.sawano.se/2012/03/controlling-message-converters-with.html) useful when trying to figure out how to use the `<mvc:message-converters>` element.