# Spring mockMvc doesn't consider validation in my test

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to set up an integration testing with mockMvc, and i have a problem with it. Indeed, spring doesn't integrate any validation annotation.

 For more precision, i put the code of the Controller class which could be tested :

```
@Controller
public class UserRegisterController {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserRegisterController.class);

    private UserManager userManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserRegisterController(UserManager userManager){
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    /**
     * Register a new user.
     *
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/User/Register", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET
    )
    public @ResponseBody SimpleMessage submitForm(
            @Valid UserInfoNew userInfo,
            BindingResult result
    ){
        if(log.isInfoEnabled())
            log.info("Execute UserRegister action");
        SimpleMessage message;

        try {
            if(result.hasErrors()){
                if(log.isFatalEnabled())
                    log.fatal("Parameters sent by user for registering aren't conform. Errors are : "
                            + result.getFieldErrors().toString());
                throw new Exception(result.getFieldErrors().toString());
            }

            User user = new User();
            user.setLogin(userInfo.getLogin());
            user.setFamilyName(userInfo.getFamilyName());
            user.setFirstName(userInfo.getFirstName());
            user.setPassword(userInfo.getPassword());
            user.setDateBirthday(userInfo.getDateBirthday());
            user.setEmail(userInfo.getEmail());
            user.setMobile(userInfo.getMobile());
            user.setAddress(userInfo.getAddress());

            userManager.createUser(user);

            User newUser = userManager.findLastUserCreated();

            //Change to null some sensitive or useless return parameters
            newUser.setPassword(null);
            //

            message = new SimpleMessage(null, newUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(log.isErrorEnabled())
                log.error("A problem of type : " + e.getClass() 
                        + " has occured, with message : " + e.getMessage());
            message = new SimpleMessage(
                            new SimpleException(e.getClass(), e.getMessage()), null);
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Then, the object with contain both hibernate and javax annotation for validation :

```
public abstract class UserParameters {

    @Min(1)
    protected Long id;

    @Length(min=4, max=20)
    protected String login;

    @Length(min=4, max=20)
    protected String familyName;

    @Length(min=4, max=20)
    protected String firstName;

    @Pattern(regexp="^.*(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+)"
            + "(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[@$%*#]+).*$")
    protected String password;

    @Past
    protected Calendar dateBirthday;

    @Email
    @Length(max=255)
    protected String email;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[0]{1}[67]{1}[ .-]{1}[0-9]{2}[ .-]{1}"
            + "[0-9]{2}[ .-]{1}[0-9]{2}[ .-]{1}[0-9]{2}$")
    protected String mobile;

    @Length(max=255)
    protected String address;

    protected Calendar dateCreation;

    protected Calendar dateLastAccess;
}

public class UserInfoNew extends UserParameters  implements Serializable{   

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4427131414801253777L;

    @NotBlank
    public String getLogin() {
            return login;
    }   
    public void setLogin(String Login) {
            this.login = Login;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
            return familyName;
    }   
    public void setFamilyName(String Name) {
            this.familyName = Name;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }   
    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
            this.firstName = FirstName;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getPassword() {
            return password;
    }   
    public void setPassword(String Password){
        this.password = Password;
    }

    public Calendar getDateBirthday() {
        return dateBirthday;
    }
    public void setDateBirthday(Calendar strBirthDay) {     
        this.dateBirthday = strBirthDay;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String Mail) {
        this.email = Mail;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String Mobile) {
        this.mobile = Mobile;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }   
    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.address = Address;
    }
}
```

and the class which realizes the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        WebInit_Test.class,
        AppConfig_Test.class,
        WebConfig_1.class,
        WebConfig_2.class,
        WebSocketConfig.class
})
public class UserControllersTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
                        .alwaysExpect(status().isOk())
                           .alwaysExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                    .build();
}

@Test
public void userRegister() throws Exception {
    //doesn't consider @Valid during test
    mockMvc.perform(get("/User/Register?Login=A&Password=aaAA&Mobile=0134320285")
            .contentType(MediaType.ALL)
    )
            .andExpect(jsonPath("error").exists());


}
}
```

When i launch the test, the error item doesn't exist, whereas login, password and mobile can't be validate by javax and hibernate annotation. Moreover, when i try to send an URL to localhost, validation worked and new user is not saved in database.

As you can see, i use a java code configuration for my web layer, i suppose the problem come from it. Moreover i download a project from the spring team in github (link : github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) which details all kind of test we can do with mockmvc. The validation one (in "org.springframework.samples.mvc.validation" package) doesn't work with my project configuration but very well with in it's original config.

To finish, i send you all my configuration classes

```
@Configuration
public class WebInit_Test extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig_Test.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig_1.class, WebConfig_2.class, WebSocketConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}

@Configuration
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml",
    "classpath:/applicationContext-datasource-test.xml",
    "classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml"
})
public class AppConfig_Test {

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "project.web",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)
)
public class WebConfig_1 extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = this.conversionService.getObject();
        addFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig_2 extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
    }

    /**
     * Configure output mapping, see 
     * {@link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823358/spring-configure-responsebody-json-format} 
     * for more information
     * 
     * @param converters
     *          a list of {@link HttpMessageConverter<?>}
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();        
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}

@Configuration
//@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages="project.web",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)
)
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/friendship", "/message", "/journey", "/information");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/client").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have just found what is responsible for the fact that validation was not consider by mockmvc. It's just a bad dependency in my pom:
 
I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and when i replaced it by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

the test work just fine!

the problem is solved, but I am wondering why the problem comes from this part. `hibernate-validator 5.1.0.Final` include javax validation in transitive dependency, so normally, this problem would never have appeared.

Comment: thanks, i had the same problem. Everything is like this with spring/hibernate, i'm getting tired of it

Comment: Also sl4j dependency

Comment: I am wondering why you had to lower the version of the hibernate validator? Is this required?

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem, and have dropped the hibernate version back from 7.0.0 FINAL to 6.1.6 to solve this.

Comment: Same here. I noticed this broken down between 6.2.5.Final and 7.0.0.Alpha.
6.2.5.Final is the last where validation annotation are respected during mvc tests.

Answer (score 9):

I got same problem, after updating validator to 5.1.0.Final. Application is working perfectly but REST tests not (@Valid annotation is not considered at all). I resolved the problem with adding one additional dependency only for tests:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Nice! Can you explain why?

Comment: not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088583/mockmvc-does-not-work-with-validation-annotated-with-valid

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-validation and it should be already there but its not working. I also tried to add it, but did not help.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using hibernate version 5.4.1.Final just add below dependency for your test

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is "provided" dependency. You can find matching dependency for you version of hibernate at maven site. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.1.Final

For example if you are using 5.4.1 version go to above link and check for provided dependencies and use it.

Comment: Why is it happening?

Comment: It expects that this dependency will be "provided" by runtime. But runtime is not having it, so we need to include it in pom

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Works for me. But why?

Comment: Could be related to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-793, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1131

Answer (score 2):

I just added

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and it worked

Comment: We have ran into this issue when upgraded from Spring boot 2.2.2-RELEASE to 2.3.12-RELEASE. After adding this dependency in our project it worked like charm.