# Configure Jackson Using Spring 4 Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-java-config

I am using a Spring 4 MVC application. I want to configure Jackson using Java Config method, specifically to set the wrap_root_value property but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can someone please provide assistance. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're not using Spring Boot. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823358/spring-configure-responsebody-json-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one objectMapper which extends the codehaus like -

```
public class JaxbJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public JaxbJacksonObjectMapper() {
        final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();

        this.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        super.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);

        this.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        super.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks